# Hidden mounted drive

Tags: windows, network-attached-storage, server-message-block

Is there a way to mount a network drive and keep it hidden or non-browsable..?

I want to mount a NAS drive to store our daily backups on, but I also want to limit access to this drive in some way so that existing files on it can't be browsed or deleted.

Basically, in the event of the server being compromised, I'd like to limit what an attacker could do to the backups.

Comment: You secure something on a network by limiting access to it with permissions, not by playing games with "hiding" it in the list of mounted drives/browsable network resources...

Comment: If a hacker is good enough to gain elevated privileges to your computer, I'm sure he'll be able to find a hidden volume

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed the tags! So its a Windows machine you are mounting this backup drive on?, use the NAS to increase the security.

I think getting the permissions right is going to be the most important aspect to securing a samba share.  You could force a particular user over that share ([Samba MAN page](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#FORCEUSER)), then lock down that users permissions over those files.  Also make sure the share is not browsable ([Samba MAN page](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#BROWSEABLE)).

Answer (score 0):

If I recall good, you can do that adding $ somewhere, on the sharename I think.

```
yourdrivenameshare$
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: This just means yourdrivenameshare$ will not show up in the list of shares by default. If you have permission and know the name, you can still access it. And you can usually find out the names of hidden shares by doing a net view \\servername /ALL.

Comment: did forget the \\servername /ALL. Well not every user know this cmd, so it can help at some point waiting for a real, secure solution. ;)